# Android 4.1+ (Javascript browser): how to disable zooming/scaling on rotation?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, viewport, zooming

Here is my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=no" />
```

It works to disable user zooming/scaling when in landscape mode. However, when starting in portrait mode, or when the user rotates at least once, zooming is re-enabled.

I tried this, but (1) the orientationchange event doesn't fire when starting in portrait mode and (2) it doesn't do anything anyway.

```
addEvent (window, 'orientationchange', function (evt) {
 var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]')
 if (viewportmeta) {
  viewportmeta.content = "initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=no"
 }
})
```

How can I disable zooming/scaling ENTIRELY on Android browsers 4.1 and up?

Note: this is an issue with Samsung's default Android browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have been fixed in 4.2.